# Combining two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, concatenation

So i have 2 POSTs coming as arrays:

$ post1   `Array ( [0] => Tipul1 [1] => tipul2 [2] => tipul3 )`

$ post2   `Array ( [0] => cant1 [1] => cant2 [2] => cant3 )`

What I want to achieve is send these in a db(the query wont be a problem) in this format(the format is a problem and the way I concatenate the values):

```
Tipul 1 - cant1 | Tipul 2 - cant2 | Tipul 3 - cant3
```

So , how can I combine those arrays and add the `-` between each value ?

Using

```
foreach ($tip as $tipq) {

    foreach ($cantitate as $cantitateq) {

        echo $tipq.''.$cantitateq. "<br>";

    }
}
```

I would get this(it makes sense):
Tipul1cant1
Tipul1cant2
Tipul1cant3
tipul2cant1
tipul2cant2
tipul2cant3
tipul3cant1
tipul3cant2
tipul3cant3

Comment: `$arr = array_combine($post1,$post2)` gives  `array('Tipul1'=>'cant1', ... );`

Comment: As long you have not show any try outs i will give only hints: You have to reformat `Tipul1` to `Tipul 1`, ... and  combine&collect all values with something like `$arr[] = "$value1 - $value2";`, collect that in an array, then that array can be `implode(' | ',$array);` then you have what you want

Answer (score 1):

You have to iterate over the elements to combine them. Take a look at this simple three step example:

```
<?php
$input = array_combine(
    ['Tipul1', 'Tipul2', 'Tipul3'],
    ['cant1', 'cant2', 'cant3']
);
$output = [];
array_walk($input, function($val, $key) use (&$output) {
    $output[] = $key . ' - ' . $val;
});
var_dump(implode(' | ', $output));
```

The output obviously is:

> string(48) "Tipul1 - cant1 | Tipul2 - cant2 | Tipul3 - cant3"